# Deploying a JavaFX 2.1+ application using Java Webstart

Tags: java, javafx-2, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm fairly new to Java, and very new to the webstart technology.  I've been tinkering around with jnlp xml files to try and get the desired "run this application, and optionally install JavaFX if it's not in your system" behaviour.  Here is my jnlp file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<jnlp spec='1.0' xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase='http://localhost/java/app' href='launcher.jnlp'>
  <information>
    <title>Test Launcher</title>
    <vendor>OzBarry</vendor>
    <description kind='one-line'>
      Test Launcher/JNLP/Webstart Demo
    </description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.1+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version='1.6+' />
    <property name="jnlp.packEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true" />
    <jar href='launcher.jar' main='true' />
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class='demo.DemoLauncher' />
  <update check="prompt-update"/>
</jnlp>
```

When I launch my application, it prompts me to download javafx (even if it's already installed, which is slightly annoying), and once it's done that, it tries to launch the app but stops with an error along the lines of "where is the javafx runtime, because I don't know!?"

I'm on Windows 7 32-bit with Java 1.7 (Java SE Runtime Environment 7u5), and it's freshly installed (I previously completely uninstalled java, wiped out my temp files, and did a fresh install).

Comment: Might be of some help - https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2293531

Comment: That seemed to be the key - toss that link in an answer, and I'll mark this as answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [JavaFX 2.0 and Java WebStart](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2293531) .